# stopping UIImageView animation gradually and smoothly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have the following simple UIImageView animation:

```
-(void) setupTheAnimation {
  self.imgView.animationImages = imagesArr;
  [self.imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:-1];
  self.imgView.animationDuration =0.9;
  [self.imgView startAnimating];
  [self performSelector:@selector(stopTheAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}

-(void) stopTheAnimation {
  [self.imgView stopAnimating];
}
```

but I face a problem when the animation stops I do not know what is the last frame it stops at !! so the ending of animation is not smooth at all.

so I need to:

**1)** know what is the last frame at which the animation ends, so I set it as the last image of the animation and this leads to a smooth stopping.

**2)** stop this animation gradually, i.e. changing its duration time before it stops to slow it down first then stop it.

[This is a link to the sample project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57066689/test/project38.zip).

Comment: I'd say this would need to be implemented as a custom animatable property on a subclass of `UIImageView`, where you set the layer's contents repeatedly to the image in the passed in array of images with a provided timing function. Wouldn't be too hard, but I don't think it's possible to accomplish an ease out effect like you're looking for with `UIImageView`'s `animationImages`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your original implementation uses `animationImages`, but I don't know of a way to use `animationImages` *directly* with a continuously variable duration.  However, this is a pretty simple feature to implement yourself.  If you do so, then you can code a dynamic duration value between images in your array.

In the following code, I replace `animationImages` with a custom stepping function, and dynamically adjust the duration **after** a stop has been requested.  Take note that this is a little different than your original code, that specified a hard end time.  This code specifies when the gear spin should **start** slowing down.

If you really have a hard animation period, you can adjust the call to `stopTheAnimation` to account for the deceleration factor you choose (I simply increase the duration by 10% per step, during deceleration, until the steps are slower than a given threshold value):

```
// my animation stops when the step duration reaches this value:
#define STOP_THRESHOLD_SECONDS 0.1f
#define NUM_IMAGES 35

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *imagesArr;
    int currentImage;
    BOOL stopRequested;
    NSTimeInterval duration;
}

-(void) setupTheAnimation {

    stopRequested = NO;
    currentImage = 0;
    duration = 0.9f / NUM_IMAGES;
    [self stepThroughImages];

    [self performSelector:@selector(stopTheAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}

- (void) stepThroughImages {

    self.imgView.image = [imagesArr objectAtIndex: currentImage];

    if (currentImage == NUM_IMAGES - 1) {
        currentImage = 0;
    } else {
        currentImage++;
    }

    if (stopRequested && duration < STOP_THRESHOLD_SECONDS) {
        // we're slowing down gradually
        duration *= 1.1f;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(duration * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self stepThroughImages];
        });
    } else if (!stopRequested) {
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(duration * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self stepThroughImages];
        });
    }
}

-(void) stopTheAnimation {
    stopRequested = YES;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I did just notice that you actually have 36 images in your project (0 to 35).  So, maybe you should change `NUM_IMAGES` in my code to `36`, since I iterate from `0` to `NUM_IMAGES - 1`.  I think the code to initialize `imagesArr` in your `viewDidLoad` method has this same problem. It doesn't actually load `GearAnimation35@2x.png`.

Answer (score 0):

I only know this by using blocks, but here's how you do that:

```
    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.9f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

                // animate what you want
                self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

            } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                // animation is completed
                self.imgView.image = image;

            }];
```

The option 'UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut' should gradually stop your animation. You could play around with other options to see the effect for yourself.

Comment: this does not apply on animationImages method I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has an issue: the amount of frames per seconds is not constant (you slow down the time).

***Are you sure you need a frame animation ?***

If your animation can be achieved with geometric (affine) transformations then it would be really better.

If your animation can be done with a combination of:

- translation
- rotation
- scaling

then this is an affine transformation.

Comment: If they were starting from scratch with this task, I would 100% agree.  Each of the 3 gears could be separate images rotated with affine transforms.  But, since they've already got the 36 images, I'd say that this might be a good bit of work (and possibly out of the scope of *programming*, and into *graphic design*).  Four or five separate images would have to be extracted: backround, 2/3 gears, and border to lay on top.  Also, the ratcheting nature of how gears move I think also makes the slight choppiness of a frame-based animation acceptable here.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I was not aware of those 36 images of gears since this is not mentioned in the original question. But your way is acceptable but the final rendering quality will remain poor since the time is discretised for a given speed and you need to slow down this speed. Anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you had to actually download the full project to see that, so it's certainly not obvious from the question alone :)